# How to use expect in Shell script like nested If Else loop?

Tags: shell, expect

I have written below Shell script which is intended to get Model name from remote host by doing SSH and executing the command.

```
#!/bin/bash

> output.csv

IFS=","

echo "IP,Model Name" >> output.csv

while read ip
do
    #echo "Current IP is: $ip"      

    model=expect -c 'spawn ssh username@'"$ip"' "show version | in cisco"; expect -re "The.*(yes/no)?"; send "yes\r";  expect -re ".*UNAUTH.*password:"; send "password\r";' | grep cisco

    echo "$ip,$model" >> output.csv

done < Check_SSH.csv
```

When I execute below command manually, then it gives expected model name as output.

**Command:**
`expect -c 'spawn ssh username@'"$ip"' "show version | in cisco"; expect -re "The.*(yes/no)?"; send "yes\r";  expect -re ".*UNAUTH.*password:"; send "password\r";' | grep cisco`

But when its put into script like above it doesn't produce any output.

Also, there are MOTD (Message of the day) configured on most of the servers and "*The authenticity of host...*" message to adding server into `.ssh/known_hosts`, So I tried to handle them in script but Expect is failing to handle the situation when MOTD doesn't appear or when remote is already present in `.ssh/known_hosts`.

Any help is highly appreciated to get this script running.

**Expected output:**

```
IP,Model Name
8.8.8.8,C9407R
8.8.8.1,C9407R
8.8.8.2,C9407R
8.8.8.3,C9407R
```

Comment: Don't ever store password in plaintext in your script. Just configure ssh with `ssh-copy-id` and run `ssh` normally. `to adding server into .ssh/known_hosts` - just don't check it with `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=false`. Please read [bashfaq How can I store the return value and/or output of a command in a variable?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002)

Comment: @KamilCuk, I know that. But this is a secured private network so, need not to worry about security.

Comment: @KamilCuk, Also, SSH Key can't be added to all remote host as these are all banking network devices, therefore I have to use passwords only.

Comment: If you can write to the filesystem, then you can install something.  Since you are creating the file 'output.csv', you can write to the filesystem.  So you can install things.

Comment: Is there a typo in the question, or are you really running `model=expect -c 'spawn ssh us...`?

Comment: That line attempts to run the command `-c` with the variable `model` set in its environment.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Yes I can write to filesystem but because of lack of intenet connectivity not possible to install some extenal package. 
Also there is no typo in question, command is running correctly most of the times when run outside script.

Comment: If your script is executing the line `model=expect -c ...` as in your question, then you are not invoking `expect` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're missing the [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) syntax to execute the expect code:

```
model=$(expect -c ...)
# ....^^.............^
```

Next, to *optionally* expect patterns, you need the `expect {patt1 action1 patt2 action2 ...}` form:

```
expect -c '
    spawn ssh username@'"$ip"' "show version | in cisco"
    expect {
        -re "The.*(yes/no)?"      {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
        -re ".*UNAUTH.*password:" {send "password\r"; exp_continue}
        eof
    }
'
```

That way, expect can match *any* of the patterns. The `exp_continue` command "loops" within the same `expect` command so you can match more than one of them. The `eof` pattern matches when ssh connection closes after the "show version ..." command has finished.

Newlines for readability.

Putting this together:

```
model=$(
    expect -c '
        spawn ssh username@'"$ip"' "show version | in cisco"
        expect {
            -re "The.*(yes/no)?"      {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
            -re ".*UNAUTH.*password:" {send "password\r"; exp_continue}
            eof
        }
    ' | grep -i cisco
)
```

I have a feeling that there's more you need to do in the `grep` part, but you didn't show the output of just the expect command.

---

update:

1. use `spawn -noecho ssh ...` so expect will not print the spawn command.
2. then, you'll get whatever output ssh needs to show for the login process, and then the "show" command output:

   - if you're expecting exactly 1 line of output, you might want to change `grep` to `tail -n 1`.
   - otherwise, show the output you get and we can help you filter out the noise.

---

update 2: filtering out the noise

I'm going to assume that the regex pattern `cisco (.*) processor` is what you need to match:

```
model=$(
    expect -c '
        log_user 0
        spawn ssh username@'"$ip"' "show version | in cisco"
        expect {
            -re "The.*(yes/no)?"       {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
            -re ".*UNAUTH.*password:"  {send "password\r"; exp_continue}
            -re "cisco (.*) processor" {puts $expect_out(1,string)}
        }
        expect eof
    '
)
```

`log_user 0` turns off the spawned process's ability to write to stdout. Expect can still capture its output though.

Comment: It's not working for: cisco Nexus9000 C9336C-FX2 Chassis

Comment: I changed regex and last line like this:  -re "cisco (.*) " {puts $expect_out(0,string)}